# IBOutlets defined in controller's .h file are not visible in Inspector

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am creating a iPad app, using XCode4 and Storyboard.  I have the exact same app on a iPhone, which works just fine.  I copied all of the controller's .h and .m files to the new iPad app.  There are NO build errors.  I am using custom cells in several UITableViews, with prototype cells.

I have 4 IBOutlets defined in a .h file, which is included in the UIView controller's .h file. I'm trying to connect the IBOutlets to the objects in the prototype cells, but when I click on the controller, the objects don't appear in the Inspector.

Any idea why?

UPDATE:  here is the code for the SiteListingCell.h.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SiteListingsCell : UITableViewCell  {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *staLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *descLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;

@end
```

Comment: Is the class of the object you're trying to connect from set correctly in IB? Also «I have 4 IBOutlets defined in a .h file, which is included in the UIView controller's .h file.» sounds like a weird setup. Which class are the `IBOutlets` actually _in_?

Comment: The IBOutlets are actually in a class called SiteListingsCell.h, which is the custom cell for the Prototype cell in the UITableView controller.  I'll modify the question above with the code.

Comment: make sure in IB the class of the object is set right..you should probably reset it no matter what if it was a copy/paste job from another project.

Comment: I commented out the .h file in it's .m file, and I do indeed get build errors.  I tried including the .h file in another .m file and tried referencing the outlets, but I couldn't. (I figured they were outlets and maybe can't be referenced that way?)

Comment: I found the problem.. would one of you please take your comment and make it an answer?  Both were right - I neglected to set the entire cell to it's class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the class of the object you're trying to connect is set correctly in IB:
[image]

Comment: Thank you... hours I spent on this, and it was right in front of me! lol